# How to get multiple plots of particular functions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pst-func

I'm trying to understand how I can get multiple plots from a set of functions to be plotted in the same window without the clutter; *i.e.*, border, axes, grid, whatever... For example, say I want the set of 100 functions `S = {f : f(x)=sin(4*(x-i))/(x-i)+cos(2*i)sin(3*i) 0<i<=5 i∈{0.05, 0.10, ... , 5.0}}` to be plotted in the same window without the clutter and so that I can rotate, scale, etc. afterwards to ultimately make as a "watermark" background that will fly diagonally across the document. I'm certain this will look quite fabulous with sufficient tinkering with the function, but for example let's go with this `S`.

---

I've got some C++ code---it's just a simple `for` loop---I've made that will help me create the list of functions---you know, metaprogramming, making code that makes code. The metaprogramming aspect of this question will be quite easy once I figure out what the general form of function plotting looks like in LaTeX---I've never plotted anything using LaTeX before.

---

How can I replace the image with these plots?

```
\backgroundsetup{%
  scale=5.75,       %% change accordingly
  angle=25,       %% change accordingly
  opacity=.1,    %% change accordingly
  color =black,  %% change accordingly
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at ([yshift=12.5pt,xshift=5pt]current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{wave.jpg}};%\includegraphics[width=5cm]{wave.jpg}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that all you are after here is 'How to create plots in (La)TeX?'.

Comment: I want plots without the clutter, that upon rotation don't pixelate, and that can handle 101 functions in one window. How does one make this plot a watermark? There is more to what I'm after here.

Comment: I don't see where 'window'  comes here: (La)TeX creates either DVI or PDF files, which have pages. Certainly plots done in LaTeX are vector-based so can be scaled/rotated without loss of precision. Watermarking is a separate but quite doable task.

Comment: My current method is to just generate the list of functions I want for my design, export as bitmap, and then incorporate into my document via `\includegraphics`; however, upon rotation of the image, pixelation occurs. I want to avoid this at all cost.

Comment: Bitmaps always have scaling issues: depending on the method you use to save them, they may also have rotation artefacts. Neither of those has anything to do with LaTeX: create vector-based plots and use them.

Comment: I see... Vector-based plots is what LaTeX can do then? Would it not be more desirable to have LaTeX create the plots rather than incorporating the image?

Comment: i=0 is not possible ;-)  (You have a division by zero)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-2)(10,5)
 \multido{\ri=0.05+0.10,\iA=0+1}{100}{%
  \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=1000,linecolor=blue!\iA]%
    {0}{10}{ sin(4*(x-\ri))/(x-\ri)+cos(2*\ri)*sin(3*\ri)}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How sensational... Minimal too...

Comment: I think the mountains in the background are following the contour of `cos(2x)sin(3x)`; that was what I wanted.

Comment: The intensity of the blue color is proportional to i

Comment: I noticed that. I'm playing with it now. Where is there documentation on how to use this? In particular, this portion: `\multido{\ri=0.05+0.10,\iA=0+5}{20}`

Comment: Run `texdoc pst-plot` and/or `texdoc multido`. And `blue!20` means 20% of blue.

Comment: That explains the `blue!\iA`, right?

Comment: yes, that's correct, explained in the documentation of `xcolor`

Comment: How would you make this cover an A4 letter entirely as a background? Also, are `\iA` and `\ri` local variables to the `\multido` environment, or can I keep using them in more `\multido`'s within the pspicture?

Comment: Use the created pdf as a background image with a default  `\includegraphics` or with package `eso-pic`. `\iA` (Integer) and `\ri`(Real) are local to `\multido`. You can use this variables in other `\multido`, that's no problem.

Answer (score 7):

Admittedly, `pstricks` is more efficient for this sort of thing since it can write postscript code for the functions directly, while TikZ/`pgf` spins its wheels at compile-time computing coordinates for all the points.

But nonetheless, a solution in plain `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[samples=400,domain=0:10,black!25]
\foreach \i in {0.05,0.10,...,10.00}
  \draw plot %
    (\x,{sin(4*(\x-\i)*180/pi)/(\x-\i)+cos(2*\i*180/pi)*sin(3*\i*180/pi)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about making it a background watermark? I want to use the existing code that I have. See edit...

Comment: @CharlyButton, `\includegraphics` supports PDF, so you could create any one of these options in a separate file and include it in your main document (vector format maintained) that way.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try that now.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example using Asymptote to create a background image that has exactly the same width as the page. (If the page had different dimensions, the height would be shrunk instead, as the code is currently written.) Since C++ seems to be your language of choice, you may appreciate that the Asymptote syntax is similar, especially compared to something like `\multido`.

This should be compiled with the `shell-escape` option enabled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text only.
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\usepackage{background}

\backgroundsetup{scale = 1, anchor, angle = 0, position = current page.center,
            contents={\includegraphics{background-image.pdf}}}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%
\begin{asypicture}{name=compile_background}
settings.outformat = "pdf";
size(@the@paperwidth, @the@paperheight);
import graph;
// Deal with what happens when denominator equals 0:
real sinc(real x) { 
    if (x == 0) return 1;
    else return sin(x)/x;
}
for (real i = 0.05; i <= 10; i += 0.05) {
    real f(real x) {
        return 4*sinc(4*(x-i)) + cos(2i)*sin(3i);
    }
    path g = graph(f, 0, 10, n=400, operator ..);
    draw(g, 0.25*black + 0.75*white);
}
shipout(prefix="background-image");
\end{asypicture}
%
\lipsum[2-11]
\end{document}
```

The result (first page only):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A solution with PGFPlots. I made the parameters similar to Paul's post, the differences are

- I showed `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` which is capable of expanding it's argument, not needed here but good to know for the case `\foreach` would not work
- `\addplot` instead of `plot`
- directly working with radian instead of multiplying a 180/pi factor, a [new feature of pgfplots 1.11](http://latex-community.org/home/news/84-news-latex-graphics-figures-tables/502-pgfplots-1-11), so at least version 1.11 is required
- no backslash before the variable x

I compiled with LuaLaTeX which provides more memory for large plots like this.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{trig format plots=rad,compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[samples=300,domain=0:10,black!30,
      hide axis,no marks]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.05,0.10,...,10.00}{
      \addplot [very thin] {sin(4*(x-#1))/(x-#1)+cos(2*#1)*sin(3*#1)};}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: multiple plots]

Answer (score 3):

Edited to show no axes.

How does this work for you?

```
\documentclass{article} 

% Declare initial packages
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Normal distribution macro
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      hide x axis,
      hide y axis,
      no markers, 
      domain=2.5:25.5, 
      samples=100,
      xlabel=\empty, 
      ylabel=\empty,
      every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
      every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
      height=5cm, width=12cm,
      xmin = 4, xmax=24,
      xtick={14}, ytick=\empty,
      enlargelimits=false, 
      clip=false,
      grid=major
  ]

        \foreach \k in {5,6,...,14} {%
  \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(\k,3.416969)};
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%` doing here? Aesthetics?

Comment: If you don't like using a macro, then don't use the macro and embed it.

Comment: You're getting the idea here with your answer, yes, but you have axes, and a some other items in the window.

Comment: What is this `#1` and `#2` business?

Comment: #1 and #2 are two variables that you declare as argument of the macro: `<function>(<argument1>,<argument2>)`. While declaring the macro, tell LaTeX that the macro has two arguments, by using `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%` etc.

Comment: I see... Thank you... Oh, and I noticed you took out the clutter.